# AngularJS Autocomplete not showing options

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, autocomplete

My Angular autocomplete is using an object array and returning the correct result list. I can access the variables and map them to name and id field, but once I do this my drop down selector won't display text.

Here is the fiddle I started with and works correctly: http://fiddle.jshell.net/59nq55rf/

Here is the fiddle using the array and fails to display text in the drop down:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ua1r8kjv/

```
    $(function () {
        var categoryList = [
           { "CategoryName": "Groceries", "CategoryID": "1" },
           { "CategoryName": "Games", "CategoryID": "2" },
           { "CategoryName": "Gadgets", "CategoryID": "3" },
        ]



        $("#Category").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");

                var matching = $.grep(categoryList, function (value) {

                    var name = value.CategoryName;
                    var id = value.CategoryID;

                    return matcher.test(name) || matcher.test(id);
                });

                response(matching);
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
  <div class="ui-widget">
        <form>
            <label for="txtEmployeeName">Developer:</label>
            <input id="Category" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitively has to do with the jQuery UI library. It seems that it is expecting the property names to be exactly "value" and "id", anything else will not work. Run the code snippet below and test it with the letter 'g' to see for yourself. The result will correctly show 3 but fail to display the ones with the incorrect property names.

```js
        $(function () {
            var categoryList = [
           { "value": "Groceries", "id": "1" },
           { "categoryname": "Games", "categoryid": "2" },
           { "doIwork": "Gadgets", "doIworkId": "3" },
        ]
            
       

            $("#Category").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");

                    var matching = $.grep(categoryList, function (value) {
    
                        var name = value.categoryname || value.doIwork || value.value;
                        var id = value.categoryid || value.doIworkId || value.id;

                        return matcher.test(name) || matcher.test(id);
                    });
                    response(matching);
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <div class="ui-widget">
        <form>
            <label for="txtEmployeeName">Developer:</label>
            <input id="Category" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: This insight helped tremendously. I guess I realized this was the case and was hoping a way to use my array without modifying. I ended up creating a custom class (see below) and build my array to use this class. All code above worked once I set "categoryList" as an array of type _CustomPair[];

Answer (score 0):

This is my custom solution for the answer posed above by @Urielzen

```
 _CustomPair[] pairList = new _CustomPair[length];

 private class _CustomPair
    {
        public string value;
        public string id;

        public _CustomPair(string curval, string curid)
        {
            value = curval;
            id = curid;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote on my own solution. This is working great for me.